# Queue data structure requiring K accesses before removal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need a specialized queue-like data structure. It can be used by multiple consumers, but each item in queue must be removed from queue after k consumers read it.

Is there any production ready implementation? Or Should I implement a queue with read-counter in each item, and handle item removal myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can push each item k times, but beware that one consumer might poll the element more than once - I have no idea if it's desired property or not.

Comment: What's up with people downvoting and voting to close questions without commenting, what do you think is wrong? Please elaborate so the asker will be able to learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: @amit I want such data structure to save memory! otherwise I could build multiple separate queue each for every consumer.

Comment: You can store just only pointer to the data. If k will not be too big you have only k*w addition memory where w is the size of queue entry plus addres on given architecture.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil In producer-consumer, you often cannot assume shared memory model, and without this assumption, using pointer is not an option.

Comment: @amit: You didn't mention anything more specific about your requirements so mine answer is as good as your question.

Comment: This is an interesting question actually: instead of trying to close it, let us try to improve the phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Derived from the source code for BlockingQueue.  Caveat emptor, not tested.

I tried to find a way to wrap Queue, but Queue doesn't expose its concurrency members, so you can't get the right semantics.

```
public class CountingQueue<E> {

    private class Entry {
        Entry(int count, E element) {
            this.count = count;
            this.element = element;
        }
        int count;
        E element;
    }

    public CountingQueue(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.items = new Object[capacity];
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock(false);
        this.condition  = this.lock.newCondition();
    }

    private final ReentrantLock lock;
    private final Condition condition;
    private final Object[] items;
    private int takeIndex;
    private int putIndex;
    private int count;

    final int inc(int i) {
        return (++i == items.length) ? 0 : i;
    }

    final int dec(int i) {
        return ((i == 0) ? items.length : i) - 1;
    }

    private static void checkNotNull(Object v) {
        if (v == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    /**
     * Inserts element at current put position, advances, and signals.
     * Call only when holding lock.
     */
    private void insert(int count, E x) {
        items[putIndex] = new Entry(count, x);
        putIndex = inc(putIndex);
        if (count++ == 0) {
            // empty to non-empty
            condition.signal();
        }
    }

    private E extract() {
        Entry entry = (Entry)items[takeIndex];
        if (--entry.count <= 0) {
            items[takeIndex] = null;
            takeIndex = inc(takeIndex);
            if (count-- == items.length) {
                // full to not-full
                condition.signal();
            }
        }
        return entry.element;
    }

    private boolean waitNotEmpty(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        long nanos = unit.toNanos(timeout);
        while (count == 0) {
            if (nanos <= 0) {
                return false;
            }
            nanos = this.condition.awaitNanos(nanos);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean waitNotFull(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        long nanos = unit.toNanos(timeout);
        while (count == items.length) {
            if (nanos <= 0)
                return false;
            nanos = condition.awaitNanos(nanos);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean put(int count, E e) {
        checkNotNull(e);
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lock();
        try {
            if (count == items.length)
                return false;
            else {
                insert(count, e);
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean put(int count, E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
        throws InterruptedException {
        checkNotNull(e);
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            if (!waitNotFull(timeout, unit)) {
                return false;
            }
            insert(count, e);
            return true;
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public E get() {
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lock();
        try {
            return (count == 0) ? null : extract();
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public E get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            if (waitNotEmpty(timeout, unit)) {
                return extract();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lock();
        try {
            return count;
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lock();
        try {
            return count == 0;
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public int remainingCapacity() {
        final ReentrantLock lock= this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return items.length - count;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lock();
        try {
            return items.length - count == 0;
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        final ReentrantLock localLock = this.lock;
        localLock.lock();
        try {
            for (int i = takeIndex, k = count; k > 0; i = inc(i), k--)
                items[i] = null;
            count = 0;
            putIndex = 0;
            takeIndex = 0;
            condition.signalAll();
        } finally {
            localLock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A memory efficient way that retains the info you need:

Each queue entry becomes a

```
Set<ConsumerID>
```

so that you ensure the k times are for k distinct consumers:  your app logic checks if the

```
set.size()==k
```

and removes it from queue in that case.

In terms of storage: you will have tradeoffs of which Set implementation based on

- size and type of the ConsumerID
- speed of retrieval requirement

E.g if k is very small and your queue retrieval logic has access to a

```
Map<ID,ConsumerId>
```

then you could have simply an Int or even a Short or Byte depending on # distinct ConsumerID's and possibly store in an Array . This is slower than accessing a set since it would be traversed linearly - but for small K that may be reasonable.